# "The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again."

Tags: magento2.3, store-view, multidomain, store-switcher, language-switcher

Everytime I'm switching from the English store view to the Italian's one and viceversa, it takes me to the equivalent homepage (no matters where I am) and it throws this error:

[image: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.]

Here's my setup:

- Magento 2.3.4 (fresh installation, self hosted)
- Nginx reverse proxy that serves Apache webserver
- 1 website, 1 store, 2 store views
- For each store view one different domain (English store view --> example.com, Italian store view --> example.it)
- I added on top of main .htaccess these env:

  ```
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
  SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
  ```

**Recap:** If, for example, I'm on **example.com/my-beautiful-product.html** [*English store view*] and I'm switching to the Italian store view, it takes me to **example.it** and it shows that error ("The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.") instead of take me on *example.it/my-beautiful-product.html* without any errors.

Any Ideas?

---

### What I tested:

- I tried to remove the NGINX reverse proxy in front of it, just exposing Apache. Same result, it does not work.
- I tried to hardcode the store view codes in */vendor/magento/module-store/Controller/Store/SwitchAction.php* at row 106 and the $requestedUrlToRedirect :

  ```
  ...
  public function execute()
  {
      $targetStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
          \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface::PARAM_NAME
      );
      $fromStoreCode = $this->_request->getParam(
          '___from_store',
          $this->storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()
      );

      $requestedUrlToRedirect = 'https://example.it/my-beautiful-product.html';
      $redirectUrl = $requestedUrlToRedirect;
      // $requestedUrlToRedirect = $this->_redirect->getRedirectUrl();
      // $redirectUrl = $requestedUrlToRedirect;

      $error = null;
      try {
          $fromStore = $this->storeRepository->get('en');
          $targetStore = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode('it');
          // $fromStore = $this->storeRepository->get($fromStoreCode);
          // $targetStore = $this->storeRepository->getActiveStoreByCode($targetStoreCode);
      } catch (StoreIsInactiveException $e) {
          $error = __('Requested store is inactive');
      } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
          $error = __("The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.");
      }
      if ($error !== null) {
          $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($error);
      } else {
          $redirectUrl = $this->storeSwitcher->switch($fromStore, $targetStore, $requestedUrlToRedirect);
      }

      $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
  }
  ...
  ```

  Here a switch url example: https://example.com/stores/store/redirect/___store/it/___from_store/en/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYudGVjbmljbWFuLml0Lz9fX19zdG9yZT1pdA%2C%2C/

Then I switched from Italian store view to the English one and **it worked!** So **it seems it does not able to get the correct values of $targetStoreCode, and $requestedUrlToRedirect**. Any ideas?

---

### Update

- On Magento 2.2.11 (fresh installation), it works great out of the box.
- On Magento 2.3.0 (fresh installation), it works partially out of the box. Url rewrite has been created just for 1 store view. So, to make it works I had to add manually the url rewrites for the other store view. Then it worked.
- On Magento 2.3.1 (fresh installation), it shows the error. The behaviour is just the same as for the 2.3.4 version.

At this point I believe it's a bug. [I reported it on the official Magento Github repository](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27540).

Comment: issue resolved or not ?

Comment: @TirthPatel The issue is NOT resolved. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.4 bug. The problem is in the view... and exactly in module-store/view/frontend/templates/switch/languages.phtml at the line 28.

WRONG

```
<li class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()) ?> switcher-option">
    <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewModel()->getTargetStoreRedirectUrl($_lang)) ?>">
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

CORRECT

```
<li class="view-<?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getCode()) ?> switcher-option">
    <a href="#" data-post='<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getTargetStorePostData($_lang) ?>'>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?>
    </a>
</li>
```

...and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

On my configuration for a Magento 2 with several stores I am using

> website

and not

> store

for the type and it works.

I have 4 websites, each with a different store (and view).

So something like

```
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=en
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_CODE=it
SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)\.example\.it MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

might work for you ?

Comment: Thanks but it does NOT work since I have just 1 website and 2 different store views.

Comment: Yep sorry, I read your question a bit too quick. Well, if it's not a typo I have no idea, as it seems you do it right. Can you possibly add a screen copy of your website/store configuration ?

Comment: Here's the screen: https://ibb.co/kg1yqNr

Comment: ok, then it looks like it should work. Last idea : have you check your Apache logs to be sure it gets the right domain name in the referer (since there is a nginx first) ? If yes, is your magento root on / or /pub ? To test if it uses the htaccess you've changed, make a typo on purpose and see if it crashes.

If it's not something like that, well sorry I have no idea left :-)

Comment: Yes, I have. The referer in Apache logs is correct. My Magento root is on /. I really don't know where I am wrong.